# Unusual behavior across different browsers

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

The code is meant to display some manually entered Holiday destinations as an unordered list and then allow a user to make a selection from a dropdown, click submit and get current weather info. My issues;

- The list and dropdown are displaying on chrome and firefox. But dont display on IE and edge.
- The submit button is working on chrome but gives me a failed to load error via the console which i understand. However the button seems not to be working at all in firefox.
- Can i get help with line 76 to ensure i am making that api call to openweatherorg correctly?

THANKS!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>TRIPIO</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
</head>
<body onload="getDate()">
    <div class="application">
        <h2>TRIPIO</h2>
        <p id="user"></p>
        <hr/>
        <h3>Top Vacation Deals <span id="date"></span></h3>
        <ul id="travel"></ul>
        <h4>Current weather info about a destination</h4>
        <form id="destform">
            <select id="list" class="field"></select><br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">
        </form>
        <div id="information"></div>
    </div>

    <script>

        var loginname = sessionStorage.getItem('username');

        document.getElementById('user').innerHTML = 'Logged in as '+ loginname;

        function getDate() {
            var d = new Date();
            document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = d;
        }

        var holidays = [
            {
                destination: 'Dubai',
                price: 350000
            },
            {
                destination: 'Paris',
                price: 470000
            },
            {
                destination: 'Mauritius',
                price: 250000
            },
            {
                destination: 'South Africa',
                price: 300000
            }
        ];

        for(var i = 0; i < holidays.length; i++){
            console.log(holidays[i].price+' is the price for a trip to '+holidays[i].destination);
            document.getElementById('travel').innerHTML += '<li>'+ holidays[i].price + ' is the price for a trip to ' + holidays[i].destination+'</li>';
            document.getElementById('list').innerHTML += '<option>' +holidays[i].destination + '</option>';
        }

        function getInfo(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var x = document.getElementById('list');
            var selection = x.options[x.selectedIndex].text; 
            console.log(selection);

            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
                        var weather = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
                        document.getElementById("information").innerHTML = "<h5>The weather is ${weather.temp} degrees farenheit</h5>";
                    }
                }

            xhttp.open('GET', 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={'+selection+'}&APPID={602fb577e945c38c4df26c7504bf23ff}',true);
            xhttp.send();

        }

        document.getElementById('destform').addEventListener('submit', getInfo, false);

    </script>
    <footer>
        <p>This web application is running purely on Javascript &copy;</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `xhttp.open('GET', 'api.openweathermap.org` that tries to open a page on **your server** ... you need `http://` or `https://` or even `//` before that

Comment: @JaromandaX That's not the only issue with the url. Currently, you wrap your selection and key in curly braces, which aren't necessary and are possibly also at fault for breaking your call. [Here](https://openweathermap.org/current) you can see some examples for calls, one of which being https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22

Comment: Thanks. I made changes to the format of the request and it seems to work. Only issue now is line 72. I seem to have an issue cos when i click submit the output i get is 'The weather is ${weather.temp} degrees farenheit' ...is the javascript nested wrongly within the output?